# Attaching WinDbg to a process

Tags: process, windbg

I have the following question: Assume that you have an executable(**program.exe**) which you let start from **cmd.exe**. So, we have

```
C:> start program.exe
```

Is it possible to attach WinDbg to the running process program.exe ? And if yes, how can I achieve that ? Is it possible ?
Note: When I let program.exe start, another commandline window opens & closes very fast. Can WinDbg catch it ? 
I tried to catch it using Immunity Debugger but no chance.

Comment: Why not just start `program.exe` from WinDbg?

Comment: cmd /k windbg program.exe

Comment: should i write that command into a batch file ?

Comment: batch file , cmd.exe , winkey + R , powershell , or a program written by you that calls WinExec() with that as the commandline argument  whatever fancies you is ok

Answer (score 5):

Usually you can attach to a process in WinDbg with <kbd>F6</kbd> or use the `-pn` command line switch. If the process terminates too fast, there are several options:

0. Run the program under the debugger. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and enter the program's name, arguments and start directory. Alternatively, specify the executable and parameters as the last arguments to WinDbg:

> *executable*
>
> Specifies the command line of an executable process. This is used to launch a new process and debug it. This has to be the final item on the command line. All text after the executable name is passed to the executable as its argument string.

0. Create a Registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\your.exe` as [described on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/xperf/image-file-execution-options) and a REGSZ `Debugger` with the path to the debugger to launch for this program automatically when the program starts
1. If the program is under your control, insert a [DebugBreak()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call or similar (`Sleep()`, `getline()`) right at the beginning.

Comment: MSDN link is dead.